# Remove unwanted new lines in vim

Tags: vim

I have a set of data in a file that looks like this:

```
1  >1st 
2  APOTPOTOPTOA
3  POTPAOTPOAOP
4  OTAAPAOAPOTA
5  APOTA
6  >2nd 
7  POATPOAOOTPA
8  OOPTPAOPOPPO
9  OOTPPOPOAOPO
10 PT
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
1 >1st
2 APOTPOTOPTOAPOTPAOTPOAOPOTAAPAOAPOTAAPOTA 
3 >2nd 
4 POATPOAOOTPAOOPTPAOPOPPOOOTPPOPOAOPOPT
```

So in vim I tried:

```
%s/[POTA]\n[POTA]/
```

but that isn't just getting rid of new lines, it is affecting other characters in the lines. It is deleting the first and the last character as well as the new line. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the letter prior to the newline and the first letter on the next line as long as it's not a '>':

```
%s/\([AOPT]\)\n\([^>]\)/\1\2/g
```

Comment: This is not quite right. It makes the first line look right, but it appends the third line to the end of the second line.

Comment: Aha. I had assumed a extra line between sets. Updated to reflect the proper data format.

Comment: That works! I am choosing this one because it allows for any number of lines to be joined together (compared to the other answer that requires it to be a uniform number). Thanks

Comment: You know you just have to ask: `g/^>/+,/\v.\ze(%$|\n\>)/j!`

Answer (score 4):

#### Simple case

Use `:join` with `:global` should do the trick.

```
:g/^>/+j! 4
```

- `:g/{pat}/{cmd}` Run `{cmd}` on every line matching pattern, `{pat}`.
- `:join` will join lines together
- `:join!` will join without touching the white-space.
- `:join` takes a range our range is the next line `+1` which can be abbreviated `+`
- `:join` can take the number of lines to join. In this case 4

#### Generalized Case

For an arbitrary number of lines use the `:join` command with a more complex range.

```
:v/^>/-2/^[^>]/,j!
```

#### Overview

`:join!` the current line with the line above it if the line does not start with `>` or if the previous line starts with `>`.

#### Glory of details

- `:v/{pat}/{cmd}` will run `{cmd}` on every line *not* matching `{pat}`
- The `:j` command takes a range: `-2/^[^>]/,`
- `:j!` means join without messing with whitespace
- The range is `-2/^[^>]/,`
- This reads start 2 line above the current line then find the next line not starting with `>`
- The ending range is the current line, `.`. However `.` can be assumed so leave it blank.

For more help see:

```
:h :j
:h :g
```

Comment: Vim golf: `g/^[^>]/-2//,j!`

Answer (score 0):

This regex can do the job:

`:%s/\(\n>.*\n\|>.*\n\)\|\n/\1`

Must be needed to assure that `>.*\n` match `>1st` line because is not proceeded by a intro character.